# JUnit not showing ExpectedException message

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I have encountered an issue while trying to run some tests using JUnit(4) with Eclipse(Ubuntu).I have a simple test class with a function `testEmptyTitle()` that should notify me if no error was thrown

```
package tests;

import workshop.WorkshopPaper;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

public class WorkshopPaperTest {
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test(expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testEmptyTitle() {
        thrown.expect(IndexOutOfBoundsException.class);
        thrown.reportMissingExceptionWithMessage("No exception thrown"); 
    }
}
```

When I try to run my test I do not see the `"No exception thrown"` message.
This is what my JUnit interface looks like after running the test :

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I think you may need to actually throw the exception somewhere in your test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExpectedException` is useful to check if there is an instance of the exception thrown by the test methods and in your code you did not throw the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, look here below:

```
@Test//remove expected exception here, it not required
public void testEmptyTitle() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    thrown.expect(IndexOutOfBoundsException.class);
    thrown.reportMissingExceptionWithMessage("No exception thrown"); 
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();//throw exception here
}
```

In general, either `@Test(expected=SomeException.class)` or `ExpectedException.expect(SomeException.class)` used to test exception behaviour of methods, but not both together.

You can look [here](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) for `ExpectedException` class API and a simple example on it's usage.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `@Test(expected=Class<T>)` when using the expected exception rule, and you also are not calling an instance of any class to throw an exception, or even just doing `throw new IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions();`

Comment: Thank you, turns out setting expect class was causing the issue. Regarding the second part of the answer, I wouldn't be throwing the exception in a test that is supposed succeed if the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use ExpectedException with expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class
delete the attribut expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class from @Test

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none(); 
@Test
public void throwsExceptionWithSpecificType() {
     thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
     thrown.reportMissingExceptionWithMessage("My MSG");
 }
```